# How does the closure mechanism work in Perl?

Tags: perl, closures

Newbie in Perl again here, trying to understand `closure` in Perl.

So here's an example of code which I don't understand:

```
sub make_saying  {
    my $salute = shift;
    my $newfunc = sub {
        my $target = shift;
        print "$salute, $target!\n";
    };
    return $newfunc;            # Return a closure
}
$f = make_saying("Howdy");      # Create a closure
$g = make_saying("Greetings");  # Create another closure
# Time passes...
$f->("world");
$g->("earthlings");
```

So my questions are:

1. If a variable is assigned to a function, is it automatically a reference to that function?
2. In that above code, can I write `$f = \make_saying("Howdy")` instead? And when can I use the `&` because I tried using that in passing the parameters (`&$f("world")`) but it doesn't work.
3. and lastly, in that code above how did the strings `world` and `earthlings` get appended to the strings `Howdy` and `Greetings`.

Note: I understand that $f is somewhat bound to the function with the parameter `"Howdy"` so that's my understanding how `"world"` got appended. What I don't understand is the 2nd function inside. How that one operates its magic. Sorry I really don't know how to ask this one.

Comment: +1 Good and well written question. I hope there are some insightful answers here :)

Comment: "# Return a closure". This is a common misunderstanding, reflected in many definitions of (lexical) "closure". The outer function actually returns a (reference to a) *function*. In doing so, a closure is formed.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I guess the reasoning is that the closure is, of necessity, carried with the function wherever it goes, so in a sense is "returned" along with the function. Or does that not fit the definition of "closure" you're hinting at here either? (Genuinely curious to understand the distinction.)

Comment: @IMSoP If we are being precise, neither `my $x = 5; return sub { 1 + $_[0]}` nor `my $x = 5; my $f = sub { $x + $_[0] }; $f->(37);` are using closures: In the 1st example, the function does not reference any variables in the outer scope. The 2nd example uses the function in the same environment where it was defined. In practice, it is best to think of closures as a function-pointer × environment pair. When the closure is called, the environment is re-installed, then the function is run. On exit, the environment is de-installed, and the callers environment is re-entered.

Comment: @amon I'm not sure I follow the two examples: in the first case, I can see that the compiler could discover that nothing from the environment is needed, and discard it; in the second, the environment never needs to be re-installed in practice. But in both, it needs to be *captured*, at least conceptually, for the language to support closures. Otherwise, a function which was passed around, with its captured environment, but never executed, would also not be a closure, which seems an impractical definition.

Comment: @IMSoP, the most important thing to realise is that the inner fn itself remains where it is defined; only a *reference* to it is returned. Therefore it is not the case of anything being "carried with the function". That notion will get you into a conceptual muddle. Before the outer function returns, all the component parts of a closure exist - namely the outer function's execution context with an inner function - but a true closure has not yet formed. A closure is formed only when a persistent external reference to the inner fn is maintained after the outer fn has returned.

Comment: And if you followed that, you should also realise that @amon's "environment is re-installed" is also incorrect. Nothing needs to be reinstalled because the relevant aspects were never uninstalled. The outer fn's execution context is *still alive* even after completion, and this is in fact the very essence of a lexical closure. For execution contexts of the *inner* fn, it is completely academic that its outer fn has returned - it will continue to have access to the outer environment.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I get that "passing around a function" is a slightly sloppy short-hand "passing around an internal reference to ..." in the same way as "passing around an object" is in most OO languages. But the phrase "stays where it is" doesn't make sense to me - in what sense was it anywhere to begin with? And I don't see how that means that passing a function reference from one context to another *creates* a closure, rather than just *retaining* something that already exists. Or why the thing being passed can't be considered a closure, as you first asserted.

Comment: Yes exactly, when I'm not being deliberately correct, I will talk about "passing a function". "Stays where it is" is my attempt to describe what happens and is designed to emphasize that a refernece is returned not the function itself, which "stays" in the execution context of its outer function. Also, passing around a function reference does not automatically create a closure. For example, passing a function reference *to* a function will not cause a closure to be formed (though we might contrive a situation in which it did).

Comment: What a closure actually *is*, is probably best explained by @amon's "function-pointer + environment pair", ie. there are two parts. Neither part on its own is a closure and for that reason it drives me nuts when I see definitions starting "a closure is a function ...".

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I think I'll have to give up, but thanks for trying to explain. It still feels to me like "returning a closure", or at least "returning a reference to a closure" is a perfectly reasonable phrase if you consider the reference returned to be to a "function-pointer + environment pair". But clearly there's something I'm not grasping about how and when that environment is "retained".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Perl, scalar variables cannot hold subroutines directly, they can only hold references. This is very much like scalars cannot hold arrays or hashes, only arrayrefs or hashrefs.

The `sub { ... }` evaluates to a coderef, so you can directly assign it to a scalar variable. If you want to assign a named function (e.g. `foo`), you have to obtain the reference like `\&foo`.

You can call coderefs like `$code->(@args)` or `&$code(@args)`.

The code

```
$f = \make_saying("Howdy")
```

evaluates `make_saying("Howdy")`, and takes a reference to the returned value. So you get a reference that points to a coderef, not a coderef itself.

Therefore, it can't be called like `&$f("world")`, you need to dereference one extra level: `&$$f("world")`.

---

A closure is a function that is bound to a certain environment.

The environment consists of all currently visible variables, so a closure always remembers that scope. In the code

```
my $x;
sub foo {
  my $y;
  return sub { "$x, $y" };
}
```

`foo` is a closure over `$x`, as the outer environment consists of `$x`. The inner sub is a closure over `$x` and `$y`.

Each time `foo` is executed, we get a new `$y` and therefore a new closure. Most importantly `$y` does not "go out of scope" when `foo` is left, but it will be "kept alive" as it's still reachable from the closure returned.
In short: `$y` is a "local state" of the closure returned.

When we execute `make_saying("Howdy")`, the `$salute` variable is set to `Howdy`. The returned closure remembers that scope.

When we execute it again with `make_saying("Greetings")`, the body of `make_saying` is evaluated again. The `$salute` is now set to `Greetings`, and the inner sub closes over this variable. This variable is separate from the previous `$salute`, which still exists, but isn't accessible except through the first closure.

The two greeters have closed over separate `$salute` variables. When they are executed, their respective `$salute` is still in scope, and they can access and modify the value.

Comment: I am slowly getting the concept here. But still it's not that clear. So question: if my understanding is correct, everytime the `make_saying` function is called, a new `$salute` is formed? right? But what is the use of `$target` there?

Comment: Hey, i think i got it, correct me if i'm wrong and ignore my first comment. Here's how i see it now: At first `$f` calls `make_saying` then `make_saying` returns the address of its subroutine, so now $f points to its subroutine (note that at that time $target is empty so only $salute is initialized). So when the last statement: `$f->("world");` It is not calling `make_saying` anymore, it is calling its subroutine instead which is pointed to by $f, thus initializing `$target`. Am i right?

Comment: `$target` is the name of the parameter expected by the inner closure when it is called. This is made a little more confusing by Perl's sub-routines not having named parameters in the normal way; in e.g. PHP, it would look like `function make_saying($salute) { $newfunc = function($target) { print "$salute, $target!\n"; }; return $newfunc; }` with `make_saying` and the anonymous closure each taking a single named parameter. `my $target = shift;` is just the standard Perl way of expecting a parameter and calling it `$target`.

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Yes, your understanding is good enough for now: calling `$f` calls the anonymous sub, not `make_saying`. The `$target` isn't special, it's just a variable inside the anonymous sub, and will be initialized once `$f` is called. I think the best way to learn about closures is to use them.

Comment: Oh, if somebody wants named parameters in Perl, there are various modules that support this, e.g. [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/BAREFOOT/Method-Signatures-20130505/lib/Method/Signatures.pm): `use Method::Signatures; func make_saying($salute){ func($target){ print "$salute, $target!\n" } }` or [syntax 'function'](https://metacpan.org/module/Syntax::Feature::Function)

Comment: @amon The ability of Perl modules to redefine the language scares me! ;)

Comment: The best explanation of closures, actually.

Comment: "The environment consists of all currently visible variables, so a closure always remembers this scope."

So in this code:

sub foo {

Comment: @mpersico Comments can't contain linebreaks. If you have a quick question, just cram all the code on one line, or link to an external code paste (e.g. a GitHub gist). Or ask a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

> If a variable is asigned to a function, is it automatically a
>   reference to that function?

No. In example the function `make_saying` return **reference another function**. Such closures do not have name and can catch a variable from outside its scope (variable `$salute` in your example).

> In that above code, can i write $f = \make_saying("Howdy") instead?
>   And when can i use the & cause i tried using that in passing the
>   parameters (&$f("world")) but it doesnt work.

No. `$f = \make_saying("Howdy")` is not what you think (read **amon** post for details). You can write `$f = \&make_saying;` which means "put into $f reference to function make_saying". You can use it later like this:

```
my $f = \&make_saying;
my $other_f = $f->("Howdy");
$other_f->("world");
```

> and lastly, In that code above how in he** did the words world and
>   earthlings got appended to the words howdy and greetings.

**make_saying** creating **my** variable which goes into lamda (`my $newfunc = sub`); that lambda is returned from **make_saying**. It holds the given word *"Howdy"* through "closing" (? sorry dont know which word in english).

Comment: but how come when i write like this `$f = sub {1}` and print $f. I can see that $f holds an address.?

Comment: @BelmarkCaday you craete anonymous function and put it into `$f`. Thats it, when you print it you see that function's address. If you want to execute it and print its result, you should call it: `$f = sub {1}; print $f->()`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the subroutine 'make_saying', it:

1. creates a DIFFERENT closure
2. assigns the received parameter to the scalar '$salute'
3. defines (creates but not execute) an inner anonymous subroutine:
   That is the reason why at that moment nothing is assigned to the scalar
   `$target` nor is the statement `print "$salute, $target!\n";` executed  .
4. finally the subroutine 'make_saying' returns a reference to the inner anonymous subroutine, that reference becomes the only way to call the (specific) anonymous subroutine.

Ever time you call each anonymous subroutine, it:

1. assign the received parameter to the scalar `$target`
2. sees also the scalar `$salute` that will have the value assigned at the moment in which was created the anonymous subroutine (when was called its parent subroutine `make_saying`
3. finally executes the statement `print "$salute, $target!\n";`