# Is it good practice to minimize sub scope in Perl with anonymous subs?

Tags: perl, scope, anonymous-function, subroutine, anonymous

Supposing I have sub1() and sub2(). sub2 is only called from sub1. Is it good practice to minimize the scope of sub2 with an anonymous sub, so that only sub1 can see sub2?

Example1 (scope not minimized):

```
sub sub_called_only_in_calc {
    #do s.th
    #return s.th
}

sub calc {
    my $n = sub_called_only_in_calc(1,2,3);
    #...

    return $n;
}
```

Example2 (scope minimized with anonymous sub):

```
sub calc {
    #my or state
    my $sub_called_only_in_calc = sub {
        #do s.th
        #return s.th
    };

    my $n = $sub_called_only_in_calc->(1,2,3);

    #or

    #my $n = sub {
        #do s.th
        #return s.th
    #}->(1,2,3);

    return $n;
}
```

Comment: This looks like opinion based question, but I would use smaller scope only for [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17039427/223226). Also I guess there is some overhead for `my $n = sub{ .. }` assignment.

Comment: If it's only called once, you can use a bare loop (`{ ... }`).

Comment: Although I have offered an answer, I believe that this question should be swiftly closed on the grounds of *"primarily opinion-based"*. We have already seen the beginnings of unprovable disagreement, and Stack Overflow is about *demonstrable solutions*.

Answer (score 4):

Different people will have different opinions, but my opinion is that using lexical scalars to localise acccess to subroutines *may* be a useful technique in situations where it is important to limit access; for instance, when those subroutines could be called maliciously by someone unauthorised, most often through a web page.

If you are considering doing it only to prevent coding mistakes (calling the wrong subroutine) or to allow multiple subroutines with the same identifier, then I would say you were wasting your time. The former is a negligible problem anyway, and I suspect it would not be significantly reduced by this measure; while the latter should usually be implemented using packages: it is what they are designed for.

The majority of Perl modules restrict access only implicity, by prefixing the subroutine identifiers with an underscore.

Remember this quote from Larry

> Perl doesn't have an infatuation with enforced privacy. It would prefer that you stayed out of its living room because you weren't invited, not because it has a shotgun

While many of Larry's original ideas can be considered to be irrelevant to the later versions of Perl, I think this one still stands.

Comment: I object. I use both package subs with underscore prefix, and coderefs in lexical variables, to distinguish between "protected" and "private" access in an intuitive way (i.e. doesn't require any additional documentation).

Comment: @StefanMajewsky: Of course you are welcome to disagree - even to object - but I wouldn't implement things that way. I would suggest that your technique *does* require additional documentation, as without it your code could easily be seen as being simply inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you optimize for. When writing maintainable code, optimizing for legibility is probably more important than optimizing for smallest scope, so you'd go with a private method in your module:

```
sub _only_called_in_calc {
    ...
}

sub calc {
    my $result = _only_called_in_calc(1,2,3);
    ...
}
```

If you're concerned that the private function can be called from everywhere using its name and package (like `Foo::Bar::_only_called_in_calc(...)`), you can store it in a lexical variable that can only be seen in the same file:

```
my $_only_called_in_calc = sub {
    ...
};

sub calc {
    my $result = $_only_called_in_calc->(1,2,3);
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, consider the following from Perl Best Practices:

```
Place original code inline.
Place duplicated code in a subroutine.
Place duplicated subroutines in a module.
```

In other words, don't place code outside of your current scope unless you're planning to use it twice. The rationale behind this is not to expose interfaces when you don't need them to reuse code.

Comment: PBP is getting a little ragged nowadays and it can be difficult to pick out the ripe fruit. But your last point is excellent, and applies to *all* procedural languages.

Comment: A variation on your second example would be [to add some extra curlies limiting the scope of the coderef](http://gist.github.com/9273452).